# How to see the different commits between 2 branches when cherry-pick was used

Tags: git, git-log, git-cherry-pick

At work, we have a codebase with a remote `master` and `release` branches. `release` always trails or is at `master`.

Sometimes we simply rebase release against master, but other times, we have to be selective and cherry-pick commits from `master` to put into `release`.

When I cherry-pick a commit from master to release, the SHA/commit has ID changes, so when doing

```
git log origin master--not release
```

it'll show the commit with the changed SHA even though there's no material difference in the commit. How can I see which commits are on `master` that are not on `commit` with these commits where the SHA changed removed?

Comment: Probably with `git log --cherry-mark`.

Comment: [`git range-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) might be helpful or maybe [`git cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry)